# ejecución de 2 funciones cuando sólo se debe ejecutar 1

Tags: javascript

Hola amigos tengo 2 funciones una que debería ejecutarse cuando se toca un botón y la otra un combobox el problema es que las 2 se ejecutan al mismo tiempo no sé cómo hacer para que solo se ejecuten cuando sean llamadas, este es el código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b1_bus").on('click', function() {
    var id = $("#txtpresu").val();
    if ($.trim(id) != '') {

      $.post("consultapresu.php ", {
        id: id
      }, function(data) {

        $(conten2).html('');
        $(conten2).html(data);

      });
    } else {
      var cod = document.getElementById("txtpresu");
      cod.setAttribute("placeholder", "NO HAY DATOS PARA CONSULTAR");
      cod.className = "herror";
    }
  });
});


$(document).change('#combito', function() {
  var cod = document.getElementById("combito").value;
  alert(cod);
  $.post("consulmonto.php ", {
    cod: cod
  }, function(data) {
    //  alert(data);

    if (data > 50000) {
      var x16 = document.getElementById("saldo");
      x16.className = "saldo";
      document.getElementById("saldo").value = '';
      document.getElementById("saldo").value = data;

    } else {
      var x16 = document.getElementById("saldo");
      x16.className = "salmal";
      document.getElementById("saldo").value = '';
      document.getElementById("saldo").value = data;
      alert('SU SALDO ESTA LLEGANDO AL LIMITE');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema del que hablas en realidad no es un problema.

Tienes un fragmento de código encerrado en la siguiente función anónima:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//.....
})
```

Esto hace que cuando el `DOM` este construido completamente, se ejecute todo lo que está dentro, independiente de si es llamado por un botón o cualquier otro elemento.

Te animo a que leas **[documentación oficial](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**, para que entiendas el código que utilizas. Mucha suerte!